# Sql 2008 Restore backup file problem

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a  sql database backup in my system with extension *.bak.

Once I restore the database in sql 2008 it restore the database correctly.the problem arise only when it try to add some more fields to a particular table of the backup database.

Once I add some field and click on save it says

> Unable to modify table.
>   Save changes are not permitted.the changes you have made require the following tables to be dropped and re-created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is caused by a flag in SSMS: nothing to do with the restore

- Tools..Options..Designers..Table and Database Designers
- uncheck "Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation"

Also mentioned on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895146.aspx) as "Save (Not Permitted) Dialog Box"